# How to change MySQL data directory to workspace folder for syncing databace between devices?

Tags: mysql, windows

My problem is that I want to have my MySQL database in my workspace folder. I want to sync my database for all of my workdevices, so that i dont have to export my data every single time a change something.

I tried to create just a softlink to the direktory on every device I use with the `mklink /D` command in the commandline but I see that this doesn'n work.

Have you any idea how i can configure my database right this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a dedicated database server. Syncing raw MySQL data files is not the right way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution on stackexchange site : [change data dir path](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24403/change-existing-datadir-path)

Just follow the step by step solution by RolandoMySQLDBA

Comment: that is only how i change the hole directory of my databases!! I only want ONE database to be on a new directory